# Neopixel not working with Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: pi-pico, circuitpython

My neopixels aren't working when I run them, I am using curcuitpython and using all libraries required

```
import neopixel
from adafruit_led_animation.animation.solid import Solid
from adafruit_led_animation.color import RED

pixel_pin = board.GP0
pixel_num = 8

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(pixel_pin, pixel_num, brightness=0.2, auto_write=False)
```

I keep getting this in the console

```
TypeError: function missing required positional argument #3
```

The same thing happens when I try normal neopixel code

```
import time
import board
from rainbowio import colorwheel
import neopixel

# Update this to match the number of NeoPixel LEDs connected to your board.
num_pixels = 8

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.GP0, num_pixels, auto_write=False)
pixels.brightness = 0.5


def rainbow(speed):
    for j in range(255):
        for i in range(num_pixels):
            pixel_index = (i * 256 // num_pixels) + j
            pixels[i] = colorwheel(pixel_index & 255)
        pixels.show()
        time.sleep(speed)


while True:
    rainbow(0)
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help. PLEASE

Comment: Quick guess -- this: `neopixel.NeoPixel(pixel_pin, pixel_num, brightness=0.2, ` is missing an argument in between `pixel_num` and `brightness=`.

Comment: Maybe, I only recently joined the python community and have very little experience with it.

Comment: This is code from the adafruit website and I plan to modify it when it's fixed

Comment: which version of circuitpython are you running?

Comment: I am running 7.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check that you have the neopixel.py file installed in the lib folder of the circuitpy device, not the neopixel.mpy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/121227)